# R Class Error in my project

Tags: android

I get a R Class Error in my project. I tried cleaning the project, changing the property and restarting Eclipse.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        applicationContext = this.getApplicationContext();
        eventData = new EventDataSQLHelper(this);

        btnforAway = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnforAway);
        btnforDriving = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnforDriving);
        txtDefaultmain = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDefaultmain);

        btnforAway.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AppMode = AWAY_MODE;

                launchAway();

            }
        });
```

here I get R.id Error in every file of my project

Comment: So you either have som eerrors in your xml files or the file names use invelid characters. Fix the things up and then do a Project/Clean.

Comment: Are you using the right R class? You have an Android R-class and one specific for you project. Please check your imports which one you are using.

Comment: check your imports, if you import R class from your project and mostly this can be caused by errors in XML

Comment: Replace R.java file from creating new android project in to your gen folder, then successfully work....

Comment: I could not find R.java file in my project .pleass let me know what i need to do?

Comment: please create new project in android then copy R.java file from that project to your project in gen folder

Comment: There is to the different possible problems, first you make sure you are not importing android.R or you make sure that the buid path is corrent

Comment: no any problem to replace R.java file. I dem sure.

Answer (score 1):

If there is any  error in your resource folder ,R.java file will not generate automatically.
Check your console for errors in your xml .And If you create any image in drawable folder with caps lock or numbers that time also R.java file is not generate automatically.

If there is no errors in Console follow these steps :

1. `Project==>uncheck Build automatically`
2. `Project==>Clean`
3. Right click on project and select `Build project`
4. Right click on project and select `Android tools` and select `Fix project properties`

Answer (score 0):

Most of times R Class errors are related with wrong XML files build. Check all your layouts (XML files) for any error, tag or character not set properly, fix them and clean the project.